# Datatables not working with 5 columns or less

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I have been working with Datatables plugin on my Laravel 5.2 project.

I'm feeding the table with jQuery and Ajax post.

This is my HTML table:

```
<table id="entidadeTable" class="table">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>Nome</th>
           <th>Descrição</th>
           <th>Ações</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

And after that I instantiate the table by Datatable:

```
var entidadeTable = $('#entidadeTable').DataTable({
    "language": {
        "url":"//cdn.datatables.net/plugins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Portuguese.json"
    },
    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
    "ajax": {
         "method": "POST",
         "url": "{{ route('getTabelaEntidades') }}",
         "data": {_token: "{{ Session::token() }}"}
    },
    "columns": [
         {"data": "id"},
         {"data": "nome"},
         {"data": "descricao"},
         {"data": "actions"}
    ],
});
```

This is my controller code, that is responsible to get the data to the datatable:

```
$entidades = Entidade::all();

return response()->json(['draw' => 1, 'recordsTotal' => $entidades->count(),
            'recordsFiltered' => $entidades->count(), 'data' => $entidades]);
```

**But I'm getting this datatable error:**

https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4

**I only get this error if my table has less than 6 columns.
I tried to put more than 5 columns on my table and after that it worked and the error disappeared**

**Error:**

```
DataTables warning: table id=entidadeTable - Requested unknown parameter '4' for row 0, column 4. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

Comment: Check out this [package](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables). It helps you a lot

Answer (score 4):

**I added this datatables property and the error disappeared**

`columnDefs: [{ }],`

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<table id="entidadeTable" class="table">
 <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Nome</th>
       <th>Descrição</th>
       <th>Ações</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
```

**return data**
Laravel returns you automatically json type.

```
return Entidade::all();
```

**datatable**

```
var entidadeTable = $('#entidadeTable').DataTable({
    "language": {
        "url":"//cdn.datatables.net/plugins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Portuguese.json"
    },
    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
    "ajax": {
         "method": "POST",
         "url": "{{ route('getTabelaEntidades') }}",
         "data": {_token: "{{ Session::token() }}"}
    },
    "columns": [
         {"data": "id"},
         {"data": "nome"},
         {"data": "descricao"},
         {"data": null, orderable: false,
                render: function(data , type, row){
                    var html ='<div class="btn-group">'+
                        '           <button type="button" onclick="edit('+row.id+');" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">' +
                        '               <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-130"></i>' +
                        '           </button>' +
                        '       </div>';
                    return html;
                },className: "center"
            }
    ],
});
```

Comment: Didn't work, because I'm not saying the required parameters: 
response()->json(['draw' => 1, 'recordsTotal' => $entidades->count(),
            'recordsFiltered' => $entidades->count(), 'data' => $entidades]);